# How do I force an image to not be split across pages in Excel 2016?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016

I'm trying to set up an expenses spreadsheet. The requirements are:

1. Each expense category is on a separate page, with its own subtotal.
2. Each page has scans of supporting documents for that category.
3. The supporting documents must be on the *same* page as the totals for that category, unless they won't fit.
4. The image and the spreadsheet must remain on my local network — the only thing that should leave this system is the final printed output.

The documents are mostly rail tickets, so they will fit on one landscape A4 page and still be readable.

I'm using Excel's subtotal function to automatically insert the page breaks. Everything is fine, except the images. Because they float, rather than being inserted into a cell, they get split across multiple pages on printing.

The page breaks are auto-inserted after two or three rows, giving not enough space to insert the images (unless you have a microscope handy when reading the output, of course :)

I tried moving the images in Page Layout view, but it spent most of its time lagging and throwing up the beachball cursor. When I did manage to get the image in place, it still split the wretched thing.

The only solutions I've found for embedding an image in a cell, rather than have it float, involved uploading the image to imgur and then putting the sheet on Google Docs before re-importing to Excel. This isn't acceptable, as it exposes private data to the public.

How can I embed the image in a cell, or mark it as not to be split across multiple pages? (I'm sure you used to be able to do this in an older version, too!)